# DocuSign visual editor on web site

Tags: docusignapi

My company want integrate DocuSign to our project. We have a implemented form workflow for EchoSign API and we want to know that DocuSign have embedded Visual Editor [image] for create **Envelope Templates** on our side. We want to create template in our service without redirect users to DocuSign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for response.

We found that possible pre-fill tags offline using native tags like DocuSignSignHere, DocuSignInitialHere: https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20CompositeTemplate%20Usage.htm

And using [automatic anchor tags](https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-admin-guide/admin-guide/use-automatic-anchor-text-with-custom-tags) fully resolve our problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `Embedded Signing` functionality that DocuSign offers.  Please see the bottom left API walkthrough listed "Embedded Signing" here:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs